# Java File making directory by path

Tags: java

I try to write some txt file using java code. Something like below.

```
public class MyMain {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        File file = new File("./qweasd/khh/sdafasd/asd.txt");
        file.mkdirs();

        try {

            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            bw.write("hello world!");
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Since I cannot sure asd.txt and the directory used existing. I used mkdirs. 
But, "asd.txt" also recognized as a directory. So, BuffereredWriter can not write value.

Structure like below.
[image]

Is there any way to make "/qweasd/khh/sdafasd/" as directory and "asd.txt" as file?

Comment: The easiest fix is to change `file.mkdirs();` to `file.getParentFile().mkdirs();`.

Answer (score 0):

That works as designed I would say . You should remove the "/asd.txt" from your file and use this path to ensure that the whole path exists.

Then you need to instantiate another file object, with path + filename for your filewriter.

```
public class MyMain {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        File folder = new File("./qweasd/khh/sdafasd");
        folder.mkdirs();
        File file = new File("./qweasd/khh/sdafasd/asd.txt");

        try {

            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            bw.write("hello world!");
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Java 6 or lower? If not, give `java.nio` a try. You can safely resolve paths and check if the filesystem objects exist or not.

See this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    // provide the path of the directory as String (relative paths are valid, too)
    String directoryPathString = "Y:\\our\\directory\\path\\";
    // along with the filename
    String filename = "somefile.txt";

    // create a Path object from the directory path you provided as String
    Path directoryPath = Paths.get(directoryPathString);

    try {
        // then create all directories that don't exist in the path
        Files.createDirectories(directoryPath);
        // create a path for the file by resolving the filename from the directory path
        Path filePath = directoryPath.resolve(filename);
        // then check if the file already exists (which may be obsolete in your case)
        if (Files.exists(filePath)) {
            // print a message about the file being already present
            System.out.println("File " 
                                + filePath.toAbsolutePath().toString()
                                + " already exists");
        } else {
            // and create it if it doesn't
            Files.createFile(filePath);
            System.out.println("File "
                                + filePath.toAbsolutePath().toString()
                                + " created");
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // this is just a stack trace print, do something more appropriate here
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Change the `directoryPathString` to the one you want to use.

Answer (score -1):

```java
File dir = new File("./qweasd/khh/sdafasd");
if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
    dir.mkdirs();
}
File file = new File(dir, "asd.txt");
```

To create a directory, the path must be a directory and not a file.
So first make sure the directory exists and if it doesn't then create it.

Note that method `isDirectory()` checks whether the path exists and whether it is the path to a directory.

Also note that if file `asd.txt` doesn't exist, it will be created.

Comment: mkdirs() is specced to silently do nothing if it already exists. Therefore, the if block is superfluous; just call dir.mkdirs().